# Is there a var_dump equivalent of php in navision development?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

¿ Is there a var_dump equivalent of php in navision ?

Like var_dump(RecRef); or var_dump(array); in Navision development

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don´t you try the debugger? You should find all the information that you are seeking there.

Comment: i used but just wanted know if can do something like i said for know more easy how are build complex data like virtual tables, arrays.. etc

Comment: What does var_dump do?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any generic dump function like var_dump (assuming PHP).
You can use the debugger to view all the fields & values on a particular record at a particular point in the code.

You could design a generic dump function that accepts a Record then turn it into a RecRef. A RecRef would let technically let you dynamically iterate through the fields and dump them out, though I've never had the need come up personally.

If you supply the underlying use-case/issue, we might be able to provide a solution.